# File path issue on Mac OS

Tags: macos, qt

I have the issue of displaying a QImage on Mac;

> QImage image0("../Images/image0.png");

The image is displayed fine on Windows and Ubuntu. This is definitely a problem with the ../ because if the full file path is used on Mac, the image is displayed correctly (I really do not want to use the full file path).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Try to put the file in the project path and use relative path.

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Comment: Think I will create a resource file and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

That file path will try to access the file relative to the application's current directory (accessible through Qt with `QDir::current()`).  If you haven't explicitly set this it may well be different between platforms.  I suspect what you're actually trying to do is access the image relative to the application executable, which is available through `QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath()`.  I find relative paths are best avoided for GUI apps.

Comment: Creating a resource file worked absolutely fine, thanks for your comment though.

Answer (score 1):

With Mac applications once they're built you have a `Application.app` file which contains a directory structure with your `Application` binary inside, so the path is relative to that. Using the resource system will make your life much easier in this case, as you can register them and Qt will compile them in.

If you right click on your application you can select `View Package Contents` and you'll be able to see the structure on the files.

Comment: Yeah, a resource file is the best option and it worked great.

Comment: There's upsides to the way OS X apps are packaged, but it definitely throws a curve ball when you're trying to work out why relative paths don't work properly across platforms.